# Chemical Scheme with tikz-visible wobbles

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, chemfig

I encountered a problem when using `chemfig`-schemes inside of a `tikzpicture` and the `visible`-`tikzset`. The chemical structures wobble upwards, but only on the second slide; every slide after that stays consistent. Maybe I should mention that I use this `tikzset` with some other figures in the same project aswell - there is no problem at all in other `tikzpicture`s. One of them uses the `chemfig`-schemes aswell.

I used a [sharelatax-project](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5741a7687135438b4bd9d049) to seperate the code from my big project so you can have a look.

See the following `gif` to see the effect I mentioned.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix that?

[image: this gif]

Comment: As not everyone is comfortable following external links, you might increase your chances to get an answer by including a MWE in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem arises because of the glossary entry `\gls{DPPM}` on the second arrow:

During the first (invisible) invocation on the arrow, `\gls{DPPM}` gets rendered as the long `Bis"-(di"-phenyl"-phos"-phino)"-methan (DPPM)` as defined in the glossary file. This causes a line break and a larger height of the (invisible) bounding box in the first frame, as compared to the subsequent frames, where all following invocations of `\gls{DPPM}` render as the shorter "DPPM".

A simple solution would be to invoke `\gls{DPPM}` at least once beforehand, or replacing the macro with just `DPPM`. Alternatively, remove the `first` field of the `DPPM` entry in the glossary file.

Comment: That's it, thank you! I used a different approach with `\glsfirst`, followed by a `\glsunset` so the multiple line for DPPM are always there.